# JAXB: how to get sources annotated by @generated by ant task?

Tags: jaxb, xjc

Is there a way to pass the option **-mark-generated**, which is applicable to xjc.bat:

```
%JAXB_HOME%\bin\xjc.bat -mark-generated c:\TEMP\my.xsd
```

to the corresponding ant task?

```
<taskdef name="xjc" classname="com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask">
   <classpath refid="classpath" />
</taskdef>

<xjc schema="my.xsd" destdir="src" package="gen.example">
  <produces dir="src/gen" includes="**/*.java" />
</xjc>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass -mark-generated and other options which are not directly supported in an  tag nested under the  tag, like this:

```
<xjc schema="simple.xsd" destdir="src" package="gen.example">
  <produces dir="src/gen" includes="**/*.java" />
  <arg line="-mark-generated"/>
</xjc>
```

See the [Ant Task reference](http://jaxb.java.net/jaxb20-ea/docs/xjcTask.html) for details. Happy marshalling!